# How to use module prelude-ls in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, livescript, prelude.ls

I program in LiveScript and use the external module `prelude-ls` to do things as chaining, mapping, folding, grep or other functional concepts.

In LiveScript, I can do

```
_ = require 'prelude-ls'
[1 2 3] |> map (*2) |> filter (> 4) |> fold (+)
```

But if I do, in TypeScript

```
import _ = require('prelude-ls');
```

I receive the following error:

```
# => Cannot find external module 'prelude-ls'
```

But I have this module installed and I use it with LiveScript.
Is there any way or any similar library to use within TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't because the `prelude-ls` module doesn't exist - it is because TypeScript doesn't have information about it.

I have checked and I can't find an already-made definition file - but you can start by creating a file named `prelude-ls.d.ts` and [adding the features you use](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/).

For example...

```
declare module PreludeLS {
    export function map<T>(func: (item: T) => T, data: T[]) : void;
}

export = PreludeLS;
```

Which would allow you to use the `map` function:

```
import _ = require('prelude-ls');

_.map(function (x: number) { return x + 2; }, [1, 2, 3]);

_.map(function (x: string) { return x + '__' }, ['A', 'B', 'C']);
```